# Extrange musixlyr symbols when using musixjt in Musixtex

Tags: musixtex

Extrange musixlyr symbols appears when using musixjt in Musixtex, it seems that musixlyr generates this issue, how to solve it?. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[bold=1]{xfakebold}
\newcommand{\barraSlash}{\setBold/\unsetBold}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixlyr}    


\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
    \setlyrics{EscalaDoM}{I II III IV V VI VII I VII VI V IV III II I}% added for hand indication
    \setsongraise1{-3mm}
    \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}4}
    \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
    \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
    \parindent0mm
    \startpiece 
    \A\assignlyrics1{EscalaDoM}% added to place handindication
    \NOtes\islurd0c\hu{cd}\en\bar
    \NOtes\hu{e}\tslur0f\hu{f}\en\bar
    \NOtes\isluru0m\hu{gh}\en\bar
    \NOtes\hl{i}\tslur0j\hl{j}\en\bar
    \NOtes\isluru0i\hl{i}\hu{h}\en\bar
    \NOtes\hu{g}\midslur{7}\tslur0l\hu{f}\en\bar
    \NOtes\islurd0e\hu{ed}\en\bar
    \NOTes\tslur0c\wh{c}\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \nolyr
    \lyricsoff
    \endpiece
\end{music}

\begin{music}
    \input musixjt
    \begin{center}
    \Bigtype Les Sabots\\[1ex]
    \end{center}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setclef1\treble
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}4}
    \parindent0mm
    \nostartrule
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    \scale{1.0}
    \startbarno=1
    \startpiece 
    %\resetlyrics
    %\nolyr
    %\lyricsoff
    %1er compás - 1ra línea
    \znotes\zchar{13}{\metron{\qu}{\;\,80}}\en
    \notes\zcharnote{g}{\hspace*{-2.05cm} \huge{\textcircled{\A\bfseries\large 47}}}\ql {jkl}\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \notes\ql {jkl}\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{10}{\hspace*{0.14cm} \barraSlash\barraSlash}}\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ql {m}\hl n\qsk\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \notes\ql {l}\hl n\qsk\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.14cm} \cbreath}}\en
    \znotes\lcn{16}{\rm Folclore Franc\^es}\en
    \alaligne
    %1er compás - 2da línea
    \notes\bhsk\isluru0n\ibl1n{-1}\qb1{non}\tslur0m\tqb1m\ql{l}\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \notes\isluru0n\ibl1n{-1}\qb1{non}\tslur0m\tqb1m\ql{j}\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.25cm} \cbreath}}\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ql {k}\hl j\qsk\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \notes\qu g\hl j\qsk\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \endpiece
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

Comment: I don't have MikTeX and thus cannot experiment with musixjt. But did you try to put \input musixjt before the second \begin{music}, active \resetlyrics before \startpiece or just start a new document?

Comment: For experimenting with this font, just download MuseJazzText.otf from ctan, then write `\font\jt MuseJazzText.otf {\jt Jazz font test}`.

Comment: @user206750 Thank you for the information. It is interesting that you suggest that musixjt would be just a font, because that should not provoke such an error as ABravo experienced.

Comment: The problem it not the font. When I comment out `%\input musixjt` the font changes but the problem persists.

Comment: @user206750 I am not through with this either. The questionmarks disappeared first, when I placed the \metron before the startpiece, of course with some new problems regarding the layout, but now the problem remains, even after deleting the auxiliary files. The code in general is not optimal: arbitrary brackets, no ending of a line with %, and unwanted spaces. That makes figuring out what is wrong, more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical point is not really a bug, but the definition of `\metron`:

```
\def\metron#1#2{{\lyricsoff\stemlength\f@ur\noteskip\t@n\p@ #1 1\ = #2\lyricson}}
```

which ends (sinds version 1.19, see musixtex.tex line 4853) with \lyricson and wants to continue the lyrics of the first music. The error does not occur when I delete the first music. With `\lyricsoff` after `\zcharnote q{\metron{\qu}{80}}` the problem seems to be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!!! for some reason the metron command cause a conflict with musixlyr (possible a bug), so I replace the command with manual equivalence.
The code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[bold=1]{xfakebold}
\newcommand{\barraSlash}{\setBold/\unsetBold}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixlyr}    

\usepackage{lilyglyphs}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \resetlyrics
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
    \setlyrics{EscalaDoM}{I II III IV V VI VII I VII VI V IV III II I}% added for hand indication
    \setsongraise1{-3mm}
    \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}4}
    \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
    \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
    \parindent0mm
    \startpiece 
    \A\assignlyrics1{EscalaDoM}% added to place handindication
    \NOtes\islurd0c\hu{cd}\en\bar
    \NOtes\hu{e}\tslur0f\hu{f}\en\bar
    \NOtes\isluru0m\hu{gh}\en\bar
    \NOtes\hl{i}\tslur0j\hl{j}\en\bar
    \NOtes\isluru0i\hl{i}\hu{h}\en\bar
    \NOtes\hu{g}\midslur{7}\tslur0l\hu{f}\en\bar
    \NOtes\islurd0e\hu{ed}\en\bar
    \NOTes\tslur0c\wh{c}\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \nolyr
    \lyricsoff
    \endpiece
\end{music}



\begin{music}
    \input musixjt
    \begin{center}
    \Bigtype Les Sabots\\[1ex]
    \end{center}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setclef1\treble
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}4}
    \parindent0mm
    \nostartrule
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    \scale{1.0}
    \startbarno=1
    \startpiece 
    %\resetlyrics
    %\nolyr
    %\lyricsoff
    %1er compás - 1ra línea
    %\znotes\zchar{13}{\metron{\qu}{\;\,80}}\en
    \znotes\zcharnote{r}{\hspace*{-0.9cm} \quarterNote\;=\;80}\en
    \notes\zcharnote{g}{\hspace*{-2.05cm} \huge{\textcircled{\A\bfseries\large 47}}}\ql {jkl}\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \notes\ql {jkl}\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{10}{\hspace*{0.14cm} \barraSlash\barraSlash}}\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ql {m}\hl n\qsk\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \notes\ql {l}\hl n\qsk\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.14cm} \cbreath}}\en
    \znotes\lcn{16}{\rm Folclore Franc\^es}\en
    \alaligne
    %1er compás - 2da línea
    \notes\bhsk\isluru0n\ibl1n{-1}\qb1{non}\tslur0m\tqb1m\ql{l}\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \notes\isluru0n\ibl1n{-1}\qb1{non}\tslur0m\tqb1m\ql{j}\loffset{3.3}{\zchar{0}{\hspace*{0.25cm} \cbreath}}\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ql {k}\hl j\qsk\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \notes\qu g\hl j\qsk\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \endpiece
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

The output is as follow:
[image: solved]

Comment: In case you want to use the musicography package, just replace the  quarterNote command with musQuarter.

Comment: Or just use: \znotes\zcharnote{r}{\hspace*{-0.5cm} \scalebox{1.6}{\musQuarter}\;=\;80}\en